# PHP SQL Insert To DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have tried a number of different ways of inserting data into my DB I have got a little further it used to just say error but now when you submit the form it loads a blank page, the data from the form isn't added to the table however ;/

```
                <form name="datainsert" method="post" action="dataInsert.php">
                    <label>Server Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Server Name" style="margin-left:90px; width:160px; padding:5px; margin-top:10px;"><br />
                    <label>Server Location:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Enter Server Location" style="margin-left:71px; width:160px; padding:5px; margin-top:10px;"><br />
                    <label>Server Operating System:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="os" placeholder="Enter Server OS" style="margin-left:16px; width:160px; padding:5px; margin-top:10px;"><br/>
                    <input style="margin-top:10px;" name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">
                </form>


<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$os = $_POST['os'];
)
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fostvm (name, location, os) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$os')");

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
    echo "Data Added Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}

?>
```

Can anyone see a syntax error or where I might be going wrong

thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: no error message is given using the code above just the white screen of the page

Comment: on mysql_query(), add or die(mysql_error), `mysql_query("INSERT INTO fostvm (name, location, os) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$os')") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

You have no `$sql variable` and you are using it `mysql_query` try this,

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // check for form submit
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $os = $_POST['os'];
        $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO fostvm (name, location, os) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$os')");
        if($result){
            echo "Data Added Successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
?>
```

Also you should use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) as [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) is `deprecated`

Comment: @user1745014 you have no `$sql variable` and you are using it, check my `answer` once again

Answer (score 0):

Try this. your code is Ok just comment this line ($result=mysql_query($sql);). use this code. why you try mysql_qury() two times in your code.

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $os = $_POST['os'];
    )
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fostvm (name, location, os) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$os')");

    //$result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
        echo "Data Added Successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }

    ?>
```